# How to download multiple pages of data from this web service?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to download data for all of the electoral candidates for the 2015 Canadian Federal Election.  There is a service called opennorth that has an API that allows you to do this by sending a request to this url:

https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/?limit=1000

1000 candidates is the limit that you are allowed in a single request, but there are certainly more.  I'm wondering how I can get the next page of results.  From their own documentation:

> To download all representatives, send a request to
>   https://represent.opennorth.ca/representatives/?limit=1000 and follow
>   the next link under the meta field until you reach the end. We host
>   the shapefiles and postal code concordances on GitHub.

This is for the "representatives" data, but I assume that it is the same for "candidates".  I don't understand what they mean by "follow the next link under the meta field until you reach the end".  Could someone enlighten me about this?

This is my script so far:

```
import urllib

with urllib.request.urlopen(r"https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1000") as url:
    with open(r"F:\electoral_map\candidates_python\candidates.js", "wb+") as f:
        f.write(url.read())
print("all done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON object that gets returned, there's an object called `meta`.

```
..."meta": {"next": "/representatives/?limit=1000&offset=1000",
            "total_count": 2140,
            "previous": null,
            "limit": 1000,
            "offset": 0}}
```

The link you need is that in `["meta"]["next"]`.

Alternatively you could just build that link by adding the `offset` URL parameter.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!